# What does this kind of arrow mean above a note/chord?

Tags: terminology

I'm playing Scherzo in D Minor (Gurlitt), in Applause book 2, and was wondering what this arrow meant. It looks like the tip of an arrow, shaded in, and I didn't know how to phrase it on Google.[image: an image of the music]

Thanks!